# How to insert a date to an Open XML worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using Microsoft Open XML SDK 2 and I'm having a really hard time inserting a date into a cell. I can insert numbers without a problem by setting `Cell.DataType = CellValues.Number`, but when I do the same with a date (`Cell.DataType = CellValues.Date`) Excel 2010 crashes (2007 too).

I tried setting the `Cell.Text` value to many date formats as well as Excel's date/numeric format to no avail. I also tried to use styles, removing the type attribute, plus many other pizzas I threw at the wall…

Can anyone point me to an example inserting a date to a worksheet?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to convert `DateTime` to `double` using function `ToOADate` i.e.:

```
DateTime dtValue = DateTime.Now;
string strValue = dtValue.ToOADate().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

then set it as `CellValue`

```
Cell cell;
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Date);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(strValue);
```

Remember to format cell using `DateTime` formatting, otherwise you will see `double` value, not date.

Comment: And watch out for the 1904 flag - dates can be set to be from 1-1-1900 or 1-1-1904 (because of a bug in how it calculates leap years).

Comment: Strangely that did not work for me. Even on Excel 2010.(CellValues.Date should not be supported on 2007)

Comment: DON'T just call ToString() and try to replace ",". Call ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) to ensure proper formatting. The compiler and Resharper even have a warning for this thing

Comment: Unfortunately this doe not work - maybe something has changed from the time the answer was posted.  Excel 365 doesn't recognise the formatting and your spreadsheet is corrupted

Answer (score 36):

I used the code provided by Andrew J, but the `DataType` `CellValues.Date` produced a corrupted xlsx-file for me.

The `DataType` `CellValues.Number` worked fine for me *(Don't forget to set `NumberFormatId`)*:

```
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
```

**My whole code:**

```
DateTime valueDate = DateTime.Now;
string valueString = valueDate.ToOADate().ToString();
CellValue cellValue = new CellValue(valueString);

Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
cell.StyleIndex = yourStyle; //StyleIndex of CellFormat cfBaseDate -> See below
cell.Append(cellValue);
```

My **CellFormat** for this cell in the Stylesheet looks like:

```
CellFormat cfBaseDate = new CellFormat() { 
 ApplyNumberFormat = true,
 NumberFormatId = 14, //14 is a localized short Date (d/m/yyyy) -> See list below
 //Some further styling parameters
};
```

If you'd like to format your date another way, here is a list of all default Excel **`NumberFormatId`'s**

```
ID  FORMAT CODE
0   General
1   0
2   0.00
3   #,##0
4   #,##0.00
9   0%
10  0.00%
11  0.00E+00
12  # ?/?
13  # ??/??
14  d/m/yyyy
15  d-mmm-yy
16  d-mmm
17  mmm-yy
18  h:mm tt
19  h:mm:ss tt
20  H:mm
21  H:mm:ss
22  m/d/yyyy H:mm
37  #,##0 ;(#,##0)
38  #,##0 ;[Red](#,##0)
39  #,##0.00;(#,##0.00)
40  #,##0.00;[Red](#,##0.00)
45  mm:ss
46  [h]:mm:ss
47  mmss.0
48  ##0.0E+0
49  @
```

Source of list: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table

*I know this list is from ClosedXML, but it's the same in OpenXML.*

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks! The accepted solution did not work for me as you say, the Date type isn't actually supported.

Answer (score 28):

When creating new `SpreadsheetDocument` from scratch, for `Date` formatting to work, minimal `Stylesheet` has to be created.

Critical are those few lines:

```
new CellFormat
{
    NumberFormatId = 14,
    ApplyNumberFormat = true
})
```

Full `Stylesheet` class:

```
using (var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    // Workbook
    var workbookPart = spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookPart.Workbook =
        new Workbook(new Sheets(new Sheet { Name = "Sheet1", SheetId = (UInt32Value) 1U, Id = "rId1" }));

    // Add minimal Stylesheet
    var stylesPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet
    {
        Fonts = new Fonts(new Font()),
        Fills = new Fills(new Fill()),
        Borders = new Borders(new Border()),
        CellStyleFormats = new CellStyleFormats(new CellFormat()),
        CellFormats =
            new CellFormats(
                new CellFormat(),
                new CellFormat
                {
                    NumberFormatId = 14,
                    ApplyNumberFormat = true
                })
    };

    // Continue creating `WorksheetPart`...
```

After `Stylesheet` is added, `DateTime` can be formatted:

```
if (valueType == typeof(DateTime))
{
    DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(date.ToOADate().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    // "StyleIndex" is "1", because "NumberFormatId=14"
    // is in the 2nd item of `CellFormats` array.
    cell.StyleIndex = 1; 
}
```

Note that `StyleIndex` value depends on the order of `CellFormat` items in the `CellFormats` array or the `Stylesheet` object. In this example `NumberFormatId = 14` item on the 2nd item in the array.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to store dates in OpenXml; by writing a number (using `ToOADate`) and setting the `DataType` to `Number` or by writing an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date and setting the `DataType` to `Date`. Note that the default `DataType` is `Number` so if you go with the first option you don't have to set the `DataType`.

Whichever method you choose, you'll need to set the style as Excel displays both methods identically. The following code shows an example of writing a date using the `Number` format (with and without explicitly setting the `DataType`) and using the ISO 8601 format.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    //fluff to generate the workbook etc
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

    Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet" };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

    var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

    //add the style
    Stylesheet styleSheet = new Stylesheet();

    CellFormat cf = new CellFormat();
    cf.NumberFormatId = 14;
    cf.ApplyNumberFormat = true;

    CellFormats cfs = new CellFormats();
    cfs.Append(cf);
    styleSheet.CellFormats = cfs;

    styleSheet.Borders = new Borders();
    styleSheet.Borders.Append(new Border());
    styleSheet.Fills = new Fills();
    styleSheet.Fills.Append(new Fill());
    styleSheet.Fonts = new Fonts();
    styleSheet.Fonts.Append(new Font());

    workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = styleSheet;

    CellStyles css = new CellStyles();
    CellStyle cs = new CellStyle();
    cs.FormatId = 0;
    cs.BuiltinId = 0;
    css.Append(cs);
    css.Count = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((uint)css.ChildElements.Count);
    styleSheet.Append(css);

    Row row = new Row();

    DateTime date = new DateTime(2017, 6, 24);

    /*** Date code here ***/
    //write an OADate with type of Number
    Cell cell1 = new Cell();
    cell1.CellReference = "A1";
    cell1.CellValue = new CellValue(date.ToOADate().ToString());
    cell1.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
    cell1.StyleIndex = 0;
    row.Append(cell1);

    //write an OADate with no type (defaults to Number)
    Cell cell2 = new Cell();
    cell2.CellReference = "B1";
    cell2.CellValue = new CellValue(date.ToOADate().ToString());
    cell1.StyleIndex = 0;
    row.Append(cell2);

    //write an ISO 8601 date with type of Date
    Cell cell3 = new Cell();
    cell3.CellReference = "C1";
    cell3.CellValue = new CellValue(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    cell3.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Date);
    cell1.StyleIndex = 0;
    row.Append(cell3);

    sheetData.AppendChild(row);

    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared String:

```
// assuming it's the first item in the shared string table
SharedStringItem sharedStringItem = new SharedStringItem();
Text text = new Text();
text.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
sharedStringTable1.Append(sharedStringItem);
```

Then later in code:

```
// assuming it's the first item in the shared string table
var cell = new Cell {CellReference = "A1", DataType = CellValues.SharedString};
var cellValue = new CellValue("0");
cell.Append(cellValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for us:

```
c.CellValue = new CellValue(datetimeValue).ToOADate().ToString());
c.DataType = CellValues.Number;
c.StyleIndex = StyleDate;
```

Set the DataType to CellValues.Number and then be sure to format the cell with the appropriate style index from the CellFormats. In our case we build a stylesheet within the worksheet, and StyleDate is an index into the CellFormats in the stylesheet.

Comment: How do you look up StyleDate??

Answer (score 0):

a) Get compatibility with Excel 2007, Excel 2007 Viewer etc.
b) DateTime before 1.1.1900 write as string.

```
DateTime dat = (DateTime)dr[dc.ColumnName];

//Not working with Excel 2007
//cell.DataType = CellValues.Date;
//cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dat.ToString("s"));

double diff = (dat - new DateTime(1899, 12, 30)).TotalSeconds / 86400.0;
if (diff > 1)
{
    cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(diff.ToString().Replace(",", "."));

    if (dat.TimeOfDay == new TimeSpan(0))
    {                                
        cell.StyleIndex = 2;   //Custom Style NumberFormatId = 14 ( d/m/yyyy)
    }
    else
    {
        cell.StyleIndex = 1;   //Custom Style NumberFormatId = 22 (m/d/yyyy H:mm)
    }
}
else
{
    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dat.ToString());
}
```